# Не выводится контент в модальном окне Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap4, modal

сайт ранее работал на bootstrap 3, после того как он был обновлен на 4 версию Bootstrap, в нем перестали срабатывать модальные окна (понимаю, что изменился способ роботы, но не знаю как исправить).

Шаблон модального окна един для всех окон, а контент генерируется в него уже динамически, ниже html код ранее используемого модального окна

```
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Загрузка..</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="te"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

ниже участок кода, с кнопкой которая вызывала модальное окно а в нем была форма входа (как пример)

```
          {% else %}
          <ul class="media_menu">
          <li class="Login_exit"><a href="{{ frontend }}/login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Войти</a></li>
          <li class="Login_exit"><a href="{{ frontend }}/register">Регистрация</a></li>
          {% endif %}
```

(если оставить все так, то при нажатии ничего не будет видно, так как код оформления и js другой версии бутстрапа нужен, но в инспеторе кода видно, что контент внутри модального окна пуст.)

Если же например отключить js бутстрапа 4 и подключить js бутстрапа 3 (модальное окно не будет видно по прежнему но нужный контент уже будет генерирован и виден в инспекторе кода.

Как произвести "типа миграцию" или может кто то, сможет направить/помочь решить данную проблему.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

на

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

или на

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, благодарю за ответ, но у меня подключен именно jquery-3.3.1

Comment: Пожалуйста) - а попробуйте поставить модальное дефолтное и посмотрите просто всплывание - если нет, то подключен ли нужный css и в нужной последовательности, и не перебивают ли пользовательские скрипты плавное течение bootstrapa)

Comment: Пробовал этот вариант, просто всплывает пустое окно (ну то есть обычное поведение модального окна) Но контент в нем не генерируется.

Comment: Не совсем знаком с js бутстрапа, что отвечает за подгрузку данных в модальное окно?

Comment: Отвечает стартовый набор скриптов - у вас должно быть указано в том, что Вы хотите разместить в модальном окне по событию data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" - и по клику на него (div, картинка и т.д.) будет вызвано соответствующее модальное окно, в котором вы и располагаете нужное - в body модального - include, готовый текст и прочее.

Comment: Спасибо, все верно, так и есть, может есть отдельный метод который используется для инклуда в контент
"{% else %}
          <ul class="media_menu">
          <li class="Login_exit"><a href="{{ frontend }}/login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Войти</a></li>
          <li class="Login_exit"><a href="{{ frontend }}/register">Регистрация</a></li>
          {% endif %}"

Пока не понимаю в чем дело(

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю - у Вас не срабатывает шаблонизатор - потому как сам бутстрап достаточно просто берет все обычное - видимо, дело не в нем, а есть еще что-то в Вашем старом варианте, что может быть включено в кастомные скрипты, что обеспечивает работу. Поэтому, думаю - не в бустрапе дело, а в дополнениях, которые внесены в Вашем старом варианте сайта.

Comment: Ну работа возвращается, как только подключить js от бутстрапа 3 го, 
А так на сайте работает только дефотное поведение модальных окон 4 бутстрапа (то есть пустое)

Comment: Наверное так и есть, это я и хотел узнать, возможно нужны какие то внешние обработчики или связи для вывода данных ссылки в модальном окне

Comment: Поставил бекап старого сайта, поменял в нем лишь версию бутстрапа, и та же ошибка, по всей видимости какой то обработчик связан с js старой версии бутстрапа(

Comment: Но если вот взять старый бекап, просто подключить к нему 4 версию бутстрапа, а перед этим подключить скрипт модального окна от 3 бутстрапа, то все будет работать, не понимаю, придется пере собирать сборку, или может есть вариант уже на предоставленных данных ? Благодарю

Comment: Ну, если еще и сборка у Вас кастомная, то тогда нужно смотреть понятно где - потому как стандарт переводится достаточно беспроблемно. А вариант есть такой - как обычно - постепенное отключение и локализация проблемного момента - друго нет - ну и посмотрите порядок подключения и отсутствия дублирования - были моменты, когда в подключаемых скриптах были интегрированные моменты, которые, если не знать, вставлялись стандартом. В общем - искать и локализовать - другого нет - любой костыль без этого будет проблемным и неправильно по сути. Пожалуйста)